# How can a delete request be redirected to a specific url in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Currently, I have made a "Like" model and have implemented "Like" and "Unlike" by post and delete requests, respectively. So after implementing Like, I want to implement Unlike, and I know that in order to implement it, I have to select the pk of that Like object, map it to url, and then send a delete request to that url. However, this method requires both url called "/post_id/like/like_id" and "/post_id/like_id", which I do not do, but try to redirect from views to "/post_id/like/like_id" when a delete request is sent to url called "/post_id/like/like". How can I make logic to proceed with the code as I think? Here's my code.

views.py

```
class CreateReadLikeView (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    is_saved = False

    def get_queryset (self) :
        return super().get_queryset().filter(post=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))

    def perform_create (self, serializer) :
        postId = self.kwargs.get('post_id')
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=postId)

        try :
            like = self.queryset.get(post=post, liked_people=self.request.user)

        except Like.DoesNotExist :
            serializer.save(liked_people=self.request.user, post=post)
            self.is_saved = True

    def create (self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
        if self.is_saved is True :
            self.is_saved = False
            return Response({'success': '해당 게시물을 좋아요 했습니다.'}, status=200)

        return Response({'message': ['이미 해당 게시물을 좋아요 하였습니다.']}, status=400)

    def list (self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        postId = self.kwargs.get('post_id')
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=postId)

        try :
            like = self.queryset.get(post=post, liked_people=self.request.user)

        except Like.DoesNotExist :
            return Response({'message': ['좋아요 하지 않음.']}, status=400)

        return Response({'success': '좋아요함.'}, status=200)

class DeleteLikeView (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsLiker]
    queryset = Like.objects.all()

    def get_queryset (self) :
        return super().get_queryset().filter(post=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))

    def destroy (self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        super().destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({'success': '해당 게시물의 좋아요를 취소했습니다.'}, status=200)
```

urls.py

```
path('post/<int:post_id>/like', CreateReadLikeView.as_view({'post': 'create', 'get': 'list', 'delete': 'destroy'})), # If a delete request is sent to this url.
path('post/<int:post_id>/like/<int:pk>', DeleteLikeView.as_view({'delete': 'destroy'})), # I want to redirect this url.
```

Comment: I don't understand the question exactly, but I think you need to replace `CreateReadLikeView.as_view({'delete': 'destroy'})` with `DeleteLikeView.as_view({'delete': 'destroy'})`

Comment: @Jasmijn It's my mistake My exact question is how to redirect to the url corresponding to DeleteLikeView when a delete request is sent to the url corresponding to CreateReadLikeView.